# populating a form from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, forms

Im retrieving some json data from an mvc controller and I want to edit it in a form.  Imhaving trouble actually populating the form with the returned data.  There is only one row of data, with three properites. Ive checked the data being returned and it is there but whenever I try to set the form value to the json data value, it just falls over.  My ajax call compltes ok, i get data back, but I just cant seem to put it into the form.  heres the bit in my ajax call that im trying to make work

```
success: function (data) {

            var frm = $("#frmAddDisclaimer");

            if ("Disclaimer_ID" in frm.elements) {
                frm.elements["Disclaimer_ID"].value = data.ID;
            }
            if ("Disclaimer_DisclaimerRef" in frm.elements) {
                frm.elements["Disclaimer_DisclaimerRef"].value = data.DisclaimerRef;
            }
            if ("htmlEditorDisclaimer_source" in frm.elements) {
                frm.elements["htmlEditorDisclaimer_source"].value = data.DisclaimerText;
            }
```

ive checked the form.elements contents at runtime, and those are the correct ID's and data has corresponding data in each 'property' as well

Comment: What JS Libs are you using on the front end?

Comment: just use regular jQuery selectors to assign the values. For example, if you have a textbox ID="Disclaimer_ID" then if($("#Disclaimer_ID")) { $("#Disclaimer_ID").val(data.ID); }

Answer (score 1):

`frm` is a jquery object, it has no elements property.
What you're looking for is the fom element inside it, you can expose it via square bracket notation `$("#frmAddDisclaimer")[0]` or just use `document.querySelector`

```
var frm = document.querySelector("#frmAddDisclaimer");
```